# Conditional jump for signed numbers with sub/add for registers assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, flags, emu8086

I have a question related to assembly 8086. 
There are several things that confuses me and I find contradictions all the times.

So I'll start with the first issue.
Last exam we were given the following short code and they asked if there will be a jump to the 'skip' label:

```
mov AL, 90h
mov BL, 20h
sub AL, BL
jg skip
```

In the answer to this question they wrote that it will not  jump because AL was compared with BL ***before*** the subtraction took place, since 90h in hexa is 10010000 in binary, sign bit is on whereas 20h in hexa is 100000, sign bit is off (if we complete it to 8 digits...right?)

Ok, so I thought I understood this but then I found (and actually checked on an emulator) the following problem in another exam:

Following the code below, what will be the hexa value of AX after the loop is done (and we reached the label 'done'?)

```
MOV AX,0
MOV CX,10

looping:
INC AX
SUB CX,1
JLE looping
```

The answer to this question is 0001 and I can't figure out why.
According to the previous question, the condition for the jump will be applied to CX and 1 ***before*** I subtract 1 from it. Following this logic, I can't understand why it will not jump to 'looping' again.

In the first round, ax is 1, 
CX is 10 in decimal which is 1010 in binary. MSB bit is 1, means it is negative for signed.
If I take the 2's of 1010, it is -6 in decimal.
CX is compared with 1 which is 0001 in binary, MSB (sign) bit is off so I don't even need to convert it to it's 2's representation.

CX is a negative number while 1 is not. JLE means jump less or equal. It is indeed less. Why doesn't it jump? 
What am I missing here or not calculating correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The sign bit is the most significant bit as per the operand size. You are using 8 bits so `10` decimal is `0000 1010` in binary and is obviously not negative. So, `JLE` will **not** jump thus `CX` will be `9` and `AX` will be `1` as you can verify in a debugger.

Comment: @Jester Thanks!! when you say 'operand' you refer to the 1?  should I always 'complete' it to 8 bits unless I compare two registers (say AX and BX) and then I need to 'complete' it to 16 bits? or what?  Also, one more question If I may...you said 10 in decimal is 00001010 in binary. For signed numbers, does that mean that 10 is also 10 in signed or should I do the 2's on it (and then get 011110110)

Comment: `10` is `10` in signed and unsigned both. Yes, `AX` and `BX` are 16 bit registers. Now that you mention it, you actually used `CX` no idea why I was talking about 8 bits sorry. Same business in 16 bits just more zeroes :)

Comment: @NateEldredge sorry it is a typo, should be mov, will edit.

Comment: @Jester Hi again, one more question thou...if I may..I'm a little confused but 10 is 00000000 00001010 for 16 bit, the 2's of it is 1111111111110101 +1 = 1111111111110110 which is 65526 so why 10 in unsigned is 10 in signed?

Comment: You only take the 2's complement (to get the absolute value) if the sign bit is set. `65526` is `-10`. Every number up to half of the unsigned range is the same. In 16 bits that means 0..32767 is the same, and 32768..65535 unsigned is -32768..-1 signed.